# setState impossible after ImagePicker's unmount and mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

*In React Native*

### **After** **ImagePicker** *(by Expo)* **is called to look for a photo on the system, unmount and then mount are called and I cannot use setState**.

*Error message:*

> Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method. )

Everything works fine on iOS simulator because there is not unmount.
But on physical Android, this is what I get.

I am new to React, so maybe this is very simple but I couldn't understand how to fix it from what I have read & watched so far.

I tried:

- Setting a function that checks isMount status to then call setState. But it always unmounted.
- I didn't find any info on the ImagePicker doc on expo

```
class SignUpStep2 extends Component {

   _pickPhoto = async () => {

      let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
         allowsEditing: true,
         aspect: [4, 3],
      })

      if (!result.cancelled) {
         this.setState({ property: value });
      }
   }

   _askPhotoPermissions = async () => {
      const permission = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)
      if (permission.status !== 'granted') {
 // Set alert message to ask to go to settings
      } else {
         this._pickPhoto()
      }
   }

   render() {
      return(
         <Button onPress={() => this._askPhotoPermissions()}>Change photo</Button>
      );
   }
}
```

I expect to successfully use setState({}). I'm sure it is simple but I couldn't figure out the answer in an afternoon.

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Can you add some more code, the wrapper(screen) component that contains the image-picker code ?

Comment: @NishantNair Added, hope it's more clear!